# Error Listing Collection mongodb BI Connector in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

i got an issue about mongodb for bi connector in ubuntu 18.04 LTS, when i want generate drdl using mongodrdl but i got an error

Failed: can't get the collection names for 'companies': error listing collections for 'companies': (Unauthorized) not authorized on companies to execute command { listCollections: 1, $db: "companies" }

[here's the for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMXdX.png)

Thank you